# Partitions or virtual mapping on device, not making file system

Tags: raspbian

I am running raspbian on raspberry pi 3 and using [pi-power-tools](https://github.com/Botspot/Pi-Power-Tools) to create a img.

When I try to make an image I get the error

mkfs.vfat: Partitions or virtual mappings on device '/dev/loop0', not making filesystem

I have no idea what this is or how to fix it. Does anyone have a clue